# How to transfer values from multiple columns to other columns using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have multiple columns in a pandas dataframe that I want to reduce from wide form to long form so that it essentially multiplies the number of rows in my dataframe by 2 and also adds a new column to indicate where each row comes from originally.

I have the following dataframe `df` where cols `a1`, `b1`, `c1`, and `d1` all belong to one group:

```
name a1 b1 c1 d1 a2 b2 c2 d2
joe  x  y  x  y  z  e  e  f 
lily x  o  x  y  z  o  e  f  
john o  y  x  q  z  f  e  q
```

I want to transform it into the **following final table** with a new column to indicate where the values originated from

```
name a1 b1 c1 d1 new_col
joe  x  y  x  y  group1
lily x  o  x  y  group1
john o  y  x  q  group1
joe  z  e  e  f  group2
lily z  o  e  f  group2
john z  f  e  q  group2
```

I've tried using melt functions but can't seem to figure out how to do it for multiple variable pairs. For instance, I can do it for 2 columns but not all 8:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.melt(df, id_vars = 'name', var_name = 'a_var', value_vars = ['a1', 'a2'])
```

which results in

```
name a_var value
joe  a1    x  
lily a1    x   
john a1    o
joe  a2    z  
lily a2    z   
john a2    z
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`wide_to_long`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) and create new columns with `group`:

```
df = (pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), 
                      stubnames=['a','b','c','d'], i=['index','name'], j='new_col')
        .droplevel(0)
        .reset_index())
df['new_col'] = 'group' + df['new_col'].astype(str)
print (df)
   name new_col  a  b  c  d
0   joe  group1  x  y  x  y
1   joe  group2  z  e  e  f
2  lily  group1  x  o  x  y
3  lily  group2  z  o  e  f
4  john  group1  o  y  x  q
5  john  group2  z  f  e  q
```

EDIT:

```
print (df)
   name var1_c var2_c var3_c var4_c var1_t var2_t var3_t var4_t
0   joe      x      y      x      y      z      e      e      f
1  lily      x      o      x      y      z      o      e      f
2  john      o      y      x      q      z      f      e      q

df = (pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), 
                      stubnames=['var1','var2','var3','var4'], 
                      i=['index','name'], 
                      j='new_col', 
                      suffix='\w+',
                      sep='_')
        .droplevel(0)
        .reset_index())
df['new_col'] = 'group' + df['new_col'].astype(str)
print (df)
   name new_col var1 var2 var3 var4
0   joe  groupc    x    y    x    y
1   joe  groupt    z    e    e    f
2  lily  groupc    x    o    x    y
3  lily  groupt    z    o    e    f
4  john  groupc    o    y    x    q
5  john  groupt    z    f    e    q
```

Or:

```
df1 = df.set_index('name')
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
df1 = df1.stack().rename_axis(['name','new_col']).reset_index()
df1['new_col'] = 'group' + df1['new_col'].astype(str)
print (df1)
   name new_col var1 var2 var3 var4
0   joe  groupc    x    y    x    y
1   joe  groupt    z    e    e    f
2  lily  groupc    x    o    x    y
3  lily  groupt    z    o    e    f
4  john  groupc    o    y    x    q
5  john  groupt    z    f    e    q
```

Comment: It seems that i get the following error `the id variables need to uniquely identify each row` as the IDs are not unique in each row

Comment: @fastlanes - add `reset_index` with `i=['index','name']` and also `droplevel(0)`, answer was edited.

Comment: With those edits, it creates an empty dataframe with the original columns and 5 new columns `new_col, a, b, c, d`

Comment: @fastlanes - seems forget for `.droplevel(0)`

Comment: I included `.droplevel(0)` still an empty dataframe

Comment: @fastlanes - what are real columns names? There are numbers 1,2...N after `['a','b','c','d']` ?

Comment: Real col names are `var1_c, var2_c ... var1_t, var2_t` so do not not end in numbers but letters which may be the issue as it seems `stubnames` assumes a number at the end?

Comment: @fastlanes - sure, it is problem. Can you change data sample?

Comment: yes I did that works for this use case thanks @jezrael. A more dynamic situation may require a more flexible approach other than `pd.wide_to_long` it seems

Comment: @fastlanes - nswer was edited with 2 new solutions

Answer (score 1):

One option is with [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/), where for this particular use case, you pass a regular expression with groups (to `names_pattern`) to aggregate the desired column labels into new groups (in `names_to`) - in this case we wish to keep the column label, so we use `.value` as a placeholder to initiate that:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

(df
.pivot_longer(
    index = 'name', 
    names_to = ('.value', 'new_col'), 
    names_pattern=r"(.)(.)")
.assign(new_col = lambda df: 'group' + df.new_col)
)
   name new_col  a  b  c  d
0   joe  group1  x  y  x  y
1  lily  group1  x  o  x  y
2  john  group1  o  y  x  q
3   joe  group2  z  e  e  f
4  lily  group2  z  o  e  f
5  john  group2  z  f  e  q
```